# Preventing other people from saving a document back to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a document library that stores Word letter templates with editable links.  I want users to be able to access the letters and be able to fill in the editable links but force them to save the document elsewhere as I want the document to  always return back to original and stop people saving the filled out document back to this document library. This is essential for GDPR to avoid sensitive letters being seen by everyone else.

Comment: Somehow I feel like you should have this template attach to a Content Type and ask user to create a document using this Content Type as default (so they would use your template.) If this is not the case, check out your template so no one can edit it, they HAVE to save it to somewhere else.